# Is it possible in Oracle to trace SQL statements that result in errors?

Tags: oracle, debugging

We have Oracle 11g in production. Application system is still under active development. It will be very handy to get SQL statements which cause any error.

Does Oracle provide a standard function to trace and log these statements and additional (debug) info?

Answer (score 7):

While I'm not sure if it's the easiest way, you can use an `after servererror on database` trigger to log all errors to a table.

From [Log all database errors to a table](http://nadvi.blogspot.com/2010/12/log-all-database-errors-to-table.html) by Ferdous Nadvi:

> ```
> drop trigger log_errors_trig;
> drop table   log_errors_tab;
>
> create table log_errors_tab (
>  error     varchar2(30),
>  timestamp date,
>  username  varchar2(30),
>         osuser    varchar2(30),
>         machine   varchar2(64),
>  process   varchar2(8),
>  program   varchar2(48));
>
> create or replace trigger log_errors_trig 
>  after servererror on database
> declare
>  var_user     varchar2(30);
>  var_osuser   varchar2(30);
>  var_machine  varchar2(64);
>  var_process  varchar2(8);
>  var_program  varchar2(48);
> begin
>  select username, osuser, machine, process, program
>  into   var_user, var_osuser, var_machine, var_process, var_program
>  from   sys.v_$session
>  where  audsid = userenv('sessionid');
>
>  insert into log_errors_tab
>    values(dbms_standard.server_error(1),sysdate,var_user,
>           var_osuser,var_machine,var_process,var_program);
> end;
> /
> ```

See also [Oracle System Event Triggers](http://psoug.org/reference/system_trigger.html) on PSOUG and the official [documentation for system event triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHHJGAJ)

Comment: I understand that this will only trace SQL calls made from PL/SQL but please let me know if this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

To find failed queries. Use following plsql trigger to find queries.

```
CREATE TABLE QUERY_LOG (ID              NUMBER,ORA_ERR         VARCHAR2(10),EXE_DATE        DATE,QRY_LOG         NCLOB);

CREATE SEQUENCE QUERY_LOG_ID NOCACHE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Failed_To_Extend_Temp
AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    l_sql_text ora_name_list_t;
    l_n        NUMBER;
    t1         NCLOB;
BEGIN
    --IF (is_servererror(942) ) THEN
    l_n := ora_sql_txt(l_sql_text );

    FOR I IN 1 .. l_n
    LOOP
        t1 := t1||l_sql_text(i);
    END LOOP;

    INSERT INTO QUERY_LOG (Id , Ora_Err , EXE_DATE , QRY_LOG)
    VALUES (QUERY_LOG_ID.Nextval, ora_server_error(1), Sysdate,t1 );
--END IF;
END;
/
```

See my YouTube video [Oracle, Find Failed Queries](https://youtu.be/CU9HXX7RR9w)